# Check for number of html element then run a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three different scenario where the span element presents.

1. No child span element:

   ```
   <div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
    <div class="outside">Type here</div>
   </div>
   ```
2. One child span element:

   ```
   <div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
    <div class="outside">Type here <span class="inside"> please.</span></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Multiple child span element with same class name

   ```
   <div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
    <div class="outside">Type here<span class="inside"> please </span> thanks</div>
    <div class="outside">Name <span class="inside"> please.</span> thanks.</div>
   </div>
   ```

I want to run the following function:

```
var len = $('span.inside').get(0).nextSibling.length;
console.log(len);
```

Because the span class can be present once or multiple times, or not at all, I want to check for the presence of the span. Then based on the number of times the span element is there, I would need to run the function for all the span element.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What about `$("span.inside").length`?

Comment: check span using class with length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var length = $('span.inside').length;

if (length > 0) {

  $('span.inside').each(function() {
    var len = $(this).get(0).nextSibling.length;
    console.log(len);
  })


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="example">
  <div class="outside">Type here<span class="inside"> please </span> thanks</div>
  <div class="outside">Name <span class="inside"> please.</span> thanks.</div>
</div>
```

1. Use class and get length.
2. For many span use `.each()` to iterate over

Answer (score 2):

> I want to check for the presence of the span.

You can achieve this by checking the length property of the selector:

```
 var $spans = $('span.inside');
 var numberOfSpans = $spans.length;
```

> Based on the number of times the span element is there, I would need to run the function for all the span element

This is a simple `if` statement, then you can use `each()` to loop over the elements in a selector:

```
if (numberOfSpans > 5) { // 5 just an example
    $spans.each(function() {
        // do something with the span here...
    });
}
```